# Preventing minidom from escaping already escaped text

Tags: python, xml, xml-serialization, escaping, minidom

```
import xml.dom.minidom

text='2 &gt; 1'

impl = xml.dom.minidom.getDOMImplementation()
doc = impl.createDocument(None, "foobar", None)
docElem = doc.documentElement
text = doc.createTextNode(text)
docElem.appendChild(text)

f=open('foo.xml', 'w')
doc.writexml(f)
f.close()
```

I expected foo.xml to read as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><foobar>2 &gt; 1</foobar>
```

but in fact it reads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?><foobar>2 &amp;gt; 1</foobar>
```

How can I stop minidom from escaping an already escaped sequence? In my application the text is being read from a (non-xml) document, so I cannot simply write `text = '2 > 1'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unescape before inserting:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

text = doc.createTextNode(unescape(text))
```

The escaping takes place when writing and cannot be disabled, nor should it be. Sometimes you *want* to include literal `&gt;` text in your XML, and that should be escaped properly for you if you do. If your input is XML escaped, simply unescape it before inserting.